# count child records based on parent and date sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am tryin to find the number of child records associated to a parent. This is based on 2 columns in the same table (master_ref for parent and ref for child). The difficulty i am finding  is to only count the child if they have the same date_entered as the parent. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also, could you please show a table structure? For example, if the `date_entered` is in a child table that's an important fact to know.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work for you:

```
select parent.master_ref, COUNT(*)
from nodes parent join
     nodes child
     on child.ref = parent.master_ref
where parent.date = child.date
group by parent.master_ref;
```

You need to do a join in order to compare values between the parent and the child.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have 3 tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE Parents (ID INT, date_entered DATE);
CREATE TABLE Children (ID INT, date_entered DATE);
CREATE TABLE Relation (master_ref INT, ref INT);
```

Following select statement should give you what you want:

```
SELECT p.ID, COUNT(*)
FROM Parents p
JOIN Relation r
ON p.ID = r.master_ref
JOIN Children c
ON c.ID = r.ref
WHERE c.date_entered = p.date_entered
GROUP BY p.ID
```

SQLFiddle with that code (without data): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6e7d3/2/0

Comment: Thanks everyone, i am new to all this so just learning. The code i have put together may be far from optimal but is as follow insert into temp_nom_count_loss (ref_num_master,nominee_count) /* +APPEND */ select a.ref_num_master, count(ref_num)-1 from A3_FACT_LOST A group by ref_num_master; update A3_FACT_ACTIVE a set a.nominee_count = (select b.nominee_count from temp_nom_count b where a.ref_num_master = b.ref_num_master AND a.as_system_date = b.as_system_date) where trim(ben_type) = 'P'; update A3_FACT_ACTIVE a set a.nominee_count = 'Not relevant' where trim(ben_type) = 'N';